# How to get all links from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer, headless-browser

According to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/628, I should be able to get all links from *< a href="xyz" >* with this single line:

```
const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', a => a.href);
```

But when I try a simple:

```
console.log(hrefs)
```

I only get:

```
http://example.de/index.html
```

... as output which means that it could only find 1 link? But the page definitely has 12 links in the source code / DOM. Why does it fail to find them all?

Minimal example:

```html
'use strict';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

crawlPage();

function crawlPage() {
    (async () => {
 
 const args = [
            "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false",
        ];
        const options = {
            args,
            headless: true,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        };

 const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
        const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.goto("http://example.de", {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
            timeout: 30000
        });
     
 const hrefs = await page.$eval('a', a => a.href);
        console.log(hrefs);
  
        await page.close();
 await browser.close();
  
    })().catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });;

}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In your example code you're using `page.$eval`, not `page.$$eval`. Since the former uses `document.querySelector` instead of `document.querySelectorAll`, the behaviour you describe is the expected one.

Also, you should change your `pageFunction`in the `$$eval` arguments:

```
const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', as => as.map(a => a.href));
```

Comment: If I use page.$$eval I get "undefined" as output.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. Does that mean that the code example on the Github page is wrong?

Comment: It's 'wrong' in the sense that it doesn't work that way right now, but if you reread the issue you'll see that that example code was a bit of a "proof of concept" example of how would `$$eval` work once implemented (now it is implemented, and it works just a bit differently).

Comment: Some links might not have an `href` attribute, so `a[href]` seems like a more accurate selector.

Answer (score 6):

The [`page.$$eval()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) method runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to the page function.

Since `a` in your example represents an array, you will either need to specify which element of the array you want to obtain the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#href) from, or you will need to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) all of the `href` attributes to an array.

#### page.$$eval()

```
const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', links => links.map(a => a.href));
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) or a combination of [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1), [`elementHandle.getProperty()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname), or [`jsHandle.jsonValue()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#jshandlejsonvalue) to achieve an array of all links from the page.

#### page.evaluate()

```
const hrefs = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), a => a.href);
});
```

#### page.$$() / elementHandle.getProperty() / jsHandle.jsonValue()

```
const hrefs = await Promise.all((await page.$$('a')).map(async a => {
  return await (await a.getProperty('href')).jsonValue();
}));
```