# How to retrieve the first child HTML element but exclude all other elements with querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, puppeteer

Currently using document.querySelector with puppeteer to retrieve the video links from a Tiktok account's HTML code and am having issues retrieving exactly what I need

With this code:

```
const grabURLs = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const pgTag = document.querySelector('.tiktok-1qb12g8-DivThreeColumnContainer.eegew6e2 div div div div div')
    return pgTag.innerHTML;
})

console.log(grabURLs)
```

I receive not only the href that I need but also all of the child elements below that, how do I limit it so the only innerHTML I receive is the first child?

```
<><div class="tiktok-x6y88p-DivItemContainerV2 e19c29qe7">
    <div data-e2e="user-post-item" class="tiktok-x6f6za-DivContainer-StyledDivContainerV2 e1gitlwo0">
        <div style="padding-top: 132.653%;" />
          <div class="tiktok-yz6ijl-DivWrapper e1cg0wnj1">
             <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@nottooshabbycakes/video/7063163560238599430">
                <canvas width="75.38461538461539" height="100" class="tiktok-1yvkaiq-CanvasPlaceholder e19c29qe2"></canvas>
                <div class="tiktok-1wa52dp-DivPlayerContainer e19c29qe4">
                    <div mode="1" class="tiktok-1jxhpnd-DivContainer e1yey0rl0">
                        <img mode="1" src="https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/8ba10e1631d14b75b0bad5988c971113?x-expires=1663250400&amp;x-signature=%2F3yL04w%2FMNG9AF1TYWI51Sq41jU%3D" alt=" #corememory" loading="lazy" class="tiktok-1itcwxg-ImgPoster e1yey0rl1"></></div>
                    <div class="tiktok-11u47i-DivCardFooter e148ts220">
                        <svg class="like-icon tiktok-h342g4-StyledPlay e148ts225" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="#fff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16 10.554V37.4459L38.1463 24L16 10.554ZM12 8.77702C12 6.43812 14.5577 4.99881 16.5569 6.21266L41.6301 21.4356C43.5542 22.6038 43.5542 25.3962 41.6301 26.5644L16.5569 41.7873C14.5577 43.0012 12 41.5619 12 39.223V8.77702Z"></path></svg>
                        <strong data-e2e="video-views" class="video-count tiktok-1p23b18-StrongVideoCount e148ts222">57</strong>
```

Here is the HTML and I am trying to extract just the href but it's logging a with all elements below it

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: querySelector selects the first element matching the criteria. Your problem is that you return the innerHTML. If you're trying to get links, why not search for tags that are known to have links? Like <a> <video> <object>, etc? querySelectorAll will return all of the elements in a list that match the css selector.

Comment: Which site is this (exact URL please)? As Shmack said, if you want the links, select the links rather than some div. Something like `page.$$eval("<some optional parent container> a[href]", els => els.map(el => el.getAttribute("href")))`. See [How to get all links from the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492017/how-to-get-all-links-from-the-dom)

Comment: Sample HTML code would go a long way with this question.

Comment: Have added the HTML to help out

Comment: @LloydWalker I updated my answer to show how to extract only the URLs into an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`firstChild`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp) property.

So, the code becomes:

```
const grabURLs = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const pgTag = document.querySelector('.tiktok-1qb12g8-DivThreeColumnContainer.eegew6e2 div div div div div')
    return pgTag.firstChild.innerHTML;
})

console.log(grabURLs)
```

Comment: Presumably, the OP doesn't want the firstChild, seeing that they are trying to exclude all children...

Comment: @Shmack so why did OP say "*so the only innerHTML I receive is the first child*"

Comment: Fair. I don't know if that was edited in or not. The question itself seems to be a little confusing, given the title "How to get the HTML element but exclude all child elements with querySelector" and the statement "so the only innerHTML I receieve is the first child". Meaning - the OP could just be not properly articulating what they actually want.

Comment: @Shmack sorry I acknowledge it was weirdly worded so I've tried to make it easier to understand

Comment: It's no problem, just here to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do a quick search of the page for all of the URLs that point to videos.

Here's how to do it on Tiktok:

```js
var videos = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='/video/']");
```

**Edit:**

To get all of the URLs into their own array afterwards, just create a new one and set each element to the `href` of the anchor tag:

```js
var num = videos.length;
var links = [];
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    links.push(videos[i].href);
}
```

```js
var videos = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='/video/']");
var links = [];
var num = videos.length;
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  links.push(videos[i].href);
}
console.log(links);
```

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

section>div {
    margin: 5px;
}

section>div>a {
    width: 192px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 108px;
    display: block;
    background: #a33;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}

section>div>a:hover {
    background: #369;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div><a href="/video/aaa" title="/video/aaa">Video aaa</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/bbb" title="/video/bbb">Video bbb</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/ccc" title="/video/ccc">Video ccc</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/ddd" title="/video/ddd">Video ddd</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/eee" title="/video/eee">Video eee</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/fff" title="/video/fff">Video fff</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/ggg" title="/video/ggg">Video ggg</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/hhh" title="/video/hhh">Video hhh</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/iii" title="/video/iii">Video iii</a></div>
  <div><a href="/video/jjj" title="/video/jjj">Video jjj</a></div>
</section>
```